# create file using JS for browser

Tags: javascript, createfile

could someone tell me how can I create a file using JS for browser? Is there a way to do that without Node JS? I was trying to create a file using Node JS, fs command, but said that "fs.createWriteStream is not a function".

Comment: Did you import `fs` in Node.js?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "for browser"?

Comment: Browsers don't allow access or create files via Javascript without user's interaction.

Comment: You can create files on client side with *file-saver* https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

Answer (score 0):

You can use **File System Access API**

For example according to MDN

```
 // store a reference to our file handle
let fileHandle;

async function getFile() {
  // open file picker
  [fileHandle] = await window.showOpenFilePicker();

  if (fileHandle.kind === 'file') {
    // run file code
  } else if (fileHandle.kind === 'directory') {
    // run directory code
  }

}
```

here is the useful [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OP seems towant to write a file, not read one

Comment: i mentioned  abottom that the doc should help them ! for example to write to a file is by there [ici](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API#writing_to_files)